# The Riddle - I Own the Value Less Than Nine

Tags: riddle, word

I own the value less than nine;

Mother makes me if child get cry;

Manager checks me to find which is high;

Lose me, addicts might be about to die;

I could be either Apple or Android side;

And I have various inside and outside;

Who/What am I?

Comment: I really want to answer this! Any chance for a slight hint?

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy Let's wait and see a while :P

Comment: Added "I could be..." to make riddle more completed :D, and the answer is not affected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are a:

> Pie

I own the value less than nine;

> Pi (3.14159...) is less than 9

Mother makes me if child get cry;

> A mother can bake a child pie to make them feel better

Manager checks me to find which is high;

> A manager can check a pie graph to look into where profits are high

Lose me, addicts might be about to die;

> Pie is slang for cocaine for drug dealers/users. https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/pie/

I have various inside and outside;

> A pie can have various ingredients inside (fillings) and outside (toppings)

Comment: Nice job :D, For the title, I expect that rot13(cv*r ~= 8.54 juvpu vf fgvyy yrff gura 9) :P

Comment: Wow. That's really interesting @Confiers

Answer (score 0):

I could be either Apple or Android side;

> Referring to Either Apple Pie (The food) or Android Pie (The Operating System)

Comment: Usually, answers to questions like this try to explain line-by-line how the proposed answer fits.

Comment: Was an addition to the above Ansewr which missed out this line